# How do I get the subject public key from a PKCS7 message?

Tags: asn1, pkcs7

Quoting [RFC4562](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.6), *Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)*, section *5.6.  Signature Verification Process*:

> The recipient MAY obtain the correct public key for the signer by any means, but the preferred method is from a certificate obtained from the SignedData certificates field.

The certificates field is a `SET OF CertificateChoices` which can be any of the following:

- Certificate
- ExtendedCertificate
- AttributeCertificateV1
- AttributeCertificateV2
- OtherCertificateFormat

The first two have a `subjectPublicKey` field but the last three do not seem to. They have Attribute fields that could contain a `subjectPublicKey` I suppose -- but if they don't it makes me wonder what the point of including them as possible choices is?

Comment: Huh. I just read that part of the RFC as "Well, you can get it from anywhere, but if you can get a signed version, that's even better."

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, the public key is included in the **Certificate**. However, a PKCS7 message does not mandate the inclusion of the Certificate.

> The person signing may or may not include their X.509 certificate for the recipient to use to verify the signature. If it is not included, the recipient has to obtain a copy of the signer's certificate by other means.

(http://www.cryptosys.net/pki/manpki/pki_signeddata.html)

However, ISO 14533 (if the security product uses this standard) defines the Certificate field as Mandatory for signed data; AttributeCertificateV2 as Conditional; and, OtherCertificateFormat as Conditional.
(http://standardsproposals.bsigroup.com/Home/getPDF/2447)

Also, per https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3852.txt, two of the five certificate formats are now obsolete:

```
      CertificateChoices ::= CHOICE {
   certificate Certificate,
   extendedCertificate [0] IMPLICIT ExtendedCertificate, -- Obsolete
   v1AttrCert [1] IMPLICIT AttributeCertificateV1,       -- Obsolete
   v2AttrCert [2] IMPLICIT AttributeCertificateV2,
   other [3] IMPLICIT OtherCertificateFormat }
```